# Why the tensor algebra has the underlying ring as a direct summand?

Tags: abstract-algebra

(Hope this is not a stupid question.)

Why not define the tensor algebra as
$\mathcal{T}(M)=\bigoplus_{i \geq 1}^{\infty}\mathcal{T}^i(M)$?

**(Already solved. See the comments.)**

Comment: Isn't this the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra)?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde The index is different, which starts from 0 in the usual definition.

Comment: There is the unital and the nonunital tensor algebra. Both are used.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff Seems that your explanation makes sense. It's bad that both my book and the wiki page say nothing about this.